# Python Scraping Sites with Multiple and Nested <!DOCTYPE html> (sites with more than one declaration of <!DOCTYPE html>)

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am having trouble scraping off some websites with more than one declaration of `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I am using Python 2.7.9 with requests and BeautifulSoup from bs4. As I execute the requests.get(url), I noticed that the result captures the text from the outter `<!DOCTYPE html>` and NOT the second inner `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

My question is that is there a way, preferably using Python, to scrape all the information of a website consisting of more than 1 `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

This person also has the same problem as me; but his or her question received no answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259682/mechanize-cutting-off-html-early-python

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

**Update v1:**

I looked around StackOverflow and I encountered this post: [Using Python requests.get to parse html code that does not load at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996001/using-python-requests-get-to-parse-html-code-that-does-not-load-at-once)

The test link is http://www.anthropologie.com/anthro/product/4120200892474.jsp?cm_vc=SEARCH_RESULTS#/.

Note that the test link is not the link I am working with but the idea is pretty much the same. Both the sites uses JS to load the additional information (I should have stated this earlier but I did not realize it till now, sorry!).

After trying out Selenium to load the page I am working on (I did not try it on the test link), I still could not get the information inside the nested html.

I am certain that my code for Selenium works as intended. Any hints on how I should proceed?

Comment: can you give an example? Like what website so we could reproduce and fix?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own question.

The answer is outlined in the steps below:

1. Use an actual browser, preferably in Chrome, and visit the website in question.
2. Observe and note the GET/POST requests in the XHR tab under the Network section in Chrome (right click the website and click "Inspect Element").
3. From there, we replicate each GET/POST request in Python.
4. For each GET/POST request, we can just scrape off the information normally.

No need to use Selenium!