# Scraping HTML code using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to scrape some image data from some stores. For example, I was looking at some images from Nordstrom (tested with 'https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/men/clothing/sweaters').

I had initially used requests.get() to get the code, but I noticed that I was getting some javascript -- and upon further researc I found that this occured because it was dynamically loaded in the html using javascript.

To remedy this issue, following this post ([Python requests.get(url) returning javascript code instead of the page html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54396285/python-requests-geturl-returning-javascript-code-instead-of-the-page-html)), I tried to use selenium to get the html code. However, I still ran into issues trying to access all the html: it was still returning alot of javascript. Finally, I added in some time delay as I thought maybe it needed some time to load in all of the html, but this still failed. Is there a way to get all the html using selenium? I have attached the current code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
def create_browser(webdriver_path):
    #create a selenium object that mimics the browser
    browser_options = Options()
    #headless tag created an invisible browser
    browser_options.add_argument("--headless")
    browser_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_path, chrome_options=browser_options)
    print("Done Creating Browser")
    return browser
url = 'https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/men/clothing/sweaters'
browser = create_browser('path/to/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
html_source = browser.page_source
print(html_source)
```

Is there something that I am not doing properly to load in all of the html code?

Comment: It seems to work if I open up the browser without the --headless tag, which suggests to me that my viewing of the page is triggering some js on the backend, or there is some issue in selenium that I made somehow.

Answer (score -1):

`browser.page_source` always returns initial HTML source but not current DOM state. Try

```
time.sleep(10)
html_source = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Comment: In general. is there a way to force load all the html? For instance, adding a wait time generates some of the html, but I have no guarantee to generate everything I need.

Additionally, do you know any reason why this would work fine when I don't add the headless argument, but fail when I add headless?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend reading "Test-Driven Development with Python", you'll get an answer for your question and so many more. You can read it for free here: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/ (and then you can also buy it ;-) )

Regarding your question, you have to wait that the element you're looking for is effectively loaded. You may use `time.sleep` but you'll get strange behavior depending on the speed of your internet connection and browser.

A better solution is explained here in depth: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_organising_test_files.html#self.wait-for

You can use the proposed solution:

```py
def wait_for(self, fn):
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        try:
            return fn()  
        except (AssertionError, WebDriverException) as e:
            if time.time() - start_time > MAX_WAIT:
                raise e
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

`fn` is just a function finding the element in the page.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a user agent. Chrome's headless user agent says `headless` that is the problem.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
def create_browser(webdriver_path):
    #create a selenium object that mimics the browser
    browser_options = Options()
    browser_options.add_argument('--headless')
    browser_options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_path, options=browser_options)
    print("Done Creating Browser")
    return browser
url = 'https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/men/clothing/sweaters'
browser = create_browser('C:/bin/chromedriver.exe')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get(url)
divs = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

Output:-
Displays all links on the page..

```
Patagonia Better Sweater® Quarter Zip Pullover
   (56)

Nordstrom Men's Shop Regular Fit Cashmere Quarter Zip Pullover (Regular & Tall)
(73)

Nordstrom Cashmere Crewneck Sweater
(51)

Cutter & Buck Lakemont Half Zip Sweater
(22)

Nordstrom Washable Merino Quarter Zip Sweater
(2)

ALLSAINTS Mode Slim Fit Merino Wool Sweater

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "Chrome's headless user agent says headless is the problem"? Additionally, when trying to follow your solution gives me a connection refused error.

Comment: @Frederick The user agent string includes HeadlessChrome instead of Chrome...when running in `--headless` mode.So, the site might be blocking it. I have added the output of the program. It works fine. Please re check your system or any copy/paste errors.

Comment: Request anyone to copy paste my code and let me know if it's not working.