# Get full content of div when performing urllib GET request

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

We have a single-page-application that is running on Node. I need to make sure that the web app is up and running. However, when I do curl or get request with urllib, I get the html content that is always displayed, even when there is an error with app compiling.

This is what is currently being returned by a get:

```
 Request Data:  b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html style="background-color: #fbfbfb; height: 100%">\n    <head>\n        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8" />\n        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">\n        <title>example</title>\n    </head>\n    <body style="min-height: 100%; margin:0">\n        <div id="app"></div>\n        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">\n        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet"> \n        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">\n        <!-- Dependencies -->\n        <!-- <script src="../node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>\n        <script src="../node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script> -->\n        \n\n        <!-- Main -->\n        <script src ="/bundle.js"></script>\n        <script src="/vendors.bundle.js"></script>\n        <script src="/main.bundle.js"></script>\n    </body>\n</html>'
```

The section that is: `<div id="app"></div>\n` has more content.

This is the content if I look at Elements in Chrome Web Tools:

```
 <div><div class="Section__container___3YYTG"><div><div><h2 class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h2">Something went wrong</h2><h6 class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h6">Loading chunk vendors~overview~siteColors~studyDetails failed.
(error: https://dev.example.com    /vendors~overview~siteColors~studyDetails.bundle.js)</h6></div></div></div></div>
```

Is there a way to get urllib get request to return the expanded data content of

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python requests.get to parse html code that does not load at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996001/using-python-requests-get-to-parse-html-code-that-does-not-load-at-once)

Comment: If you want client side scripts to run, you need a browser, use headless chrome/Firefox with selenium.